# Angular-Cli with ng-serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I know springboot use embedded tomcat web server as default so we can run application only with main method.But I have started to learn angular 6 and i saw angular-cli uses another web server.(Maybe same web server).Why do we use ng-serve command in angular-cli?We have already a embedded  Tomcat web server.How do we use 2 web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Springboot**: [Java-based web program](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)
- **Apache Tomcat**: [Java Web Servlet implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/)
- **Angular app**: JavaScript web
  program, you can think of it as a "classic" HTML + CSS + JS combination
- **Angular CLI live dev server**: [nodejs (javascrip-based) web server](https://cli.angular.io/)

The main reason for the difference is that Tomcat is a special webserver for specific java based programs, and it is not designed to run javascript file hosting.

Comment: Thank you for your replying but I used only tomcat server in a project that is based on springboot and angular.It was created with jhipster

Comment: You can deploy any classic webapplications, even Angular ones in a webserver as it is simply sending files over HTTP to the client: the Application Server platform is java specific though. You Can serve the Angular app in Tomcat - but a (local) node server can do much more than that.  http://www.thejavageek.com/2018/01/04/deploying-angular-app-tomcat/